# Specify build architecture for micronaut docker images

Tags: java, docker, maven, amazon-ec2, micronaut

I can build and run native micronaut images:

`./mvnw package -Dpackaging=docker-native -Pgraalvm`

But I'm working on an Apple M1 and pushing them to EC2 Linux. Where I get this error:

`exec /app/application: exec format error`

I believe this is because it's building for arm64 but I need it to build for amd64. Any idea how I can nudge maven to build micronaut docker images for the right architecture? (I'm currently going the long way around by defining my own Dockerfile with a --platform flag and pushing the jar into it, but this feels like it's not the standard way of doing things given micronaut can build the image for me). Thanks.